# Windows 10 creating ISO from a folder

Tags: windows-10

I've downloaded a Windows 10 ISO, I've unpacked the ISO to a folder and added an AutoUnttend.xml file to the root folder.

Now I want to rebuild the ISO, I downloaded WinCDEmu and installed, right clicked on the root folder of where I unpacked the ISO and selected "Build an ISO image" from the context menu.

I chose a location and supplied a file name then clicked the Save button.

Also instantly I get an error message:

```
mkisofs.exe reported an error. Examine the output log for more details.
```

The output log contains:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinCDEmu\mkisofs.exe: Warning: Cannot add inode hints with -no-cache-inodes.
Using TERMINALSERVICES_SESSION000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/terminalservices-sessiondirectory-server-dl.man (terminalservices-sessiondirectory-client-dl.man)
Using TERMINALSERVICES_APPSERV000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/terminalservices-appserver-licensing-dl.man (terminalservices-appserver-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_RE000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-requestmonitor-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-requestfiltering-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_NE000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-netfxextensibility45-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-netfxextensibility-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_MA000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-managementservice-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-managementscriptingtools-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_MA001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-managementscriptingtools-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-managementconsole-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_LE000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-legacysnapin-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-legacyscripts-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_IS000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-isapifilter-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-isapiextensions-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_HT000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-httpcompressionstatic-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-httpcompressiondynamic-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IIS_AS000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-iis-aspnet45-deployment-dl.man (microsoft-windows-iis-aspnet-deployment-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_FAX_CL000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-fax-client-proenterprise-dl.man (microsoft-windows-fax-client-applications-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_ERRORR000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-errorreportingfaults-dl.man (microsoft-windows-errorreportingcore-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_CERTIF000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-certificateservices-mscep-dl.man (microsoft-windows-certificateservices-camanagement-dl.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_CERTIF001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/dlmanifests/microsoft-windows-certificateservices-camanagement-dl.man (microsoft-windows-certificateservices-ca-dl.man)
Using TERMINALSERVICES_SESSION000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/terminalservices-sessiondirectory-server-replacement.man (terminalservices-sessiondirectory-client-replacement.man)
Using TERMINALSERVICES_ROLE_PA000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/terminalservices-role-package-replacement.man (terminalservices-role-package-r-replacement.man)
Using TERMINALSERVICES_GATEWAY000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/terminalservices-gateway-ui-package-replacement.man (terminalservices-gateway-ui-package-r-replacement.man)
Using TERMINALSERVICES_GATEWAY001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/terminalservices-gateway-package-replacement.man (terminalservices-gateway-package-r-replacement.man)
Using RIGHTS_MANAGEMENT_SERVIC000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/rights-management-services-role-replacement.man (rights-management-services-management-tools-replacement.man)
Using RIGHTS_MANAGEMENT_SERVIC001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/rights-management-services-management-tools-replacement.man (rights-management-services-admin-tools-replacement.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-migration-replacement.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win8.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win8.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win7.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL002.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win7.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win10.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL003.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-win10.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-vista.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL004.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-vista.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v9rs5.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL005.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v9rs5.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v8rs4.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL006.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v8rs4.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v7rs2.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL007.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v7rs2.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v6rs2.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL008.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v6rs2.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v5rs1.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL009.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v5rs1.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v4rs1.man)
Using POWERMANAGEMENT_POWERPOL00A.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v4rs1.man (powermanagement-powerpolicy-definitions-replacement-v1019h1.man)
Using NETWORKLOADBALANCINGMANA000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/networkloadbalancingmanagementheadlessserver-replacement.man (networkloadbalancingmanagementclient-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_TERMINALSE000 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-terminalservices-licenseserver (microsoft-windows-terminalservices-appserver-licensing)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_STORAG000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-storagemigration-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-storagemigration-od-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_SERVER000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-servermanager-shell-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-servermanager-rsat-roletools-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_SERVER001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-servermanager-rsat-roletools-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-servermanager-rsat-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_SERVER002.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-servermanager-rsat-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-servermanager-rsat-featuretools-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_SECURI000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-security-ngc-ctnrsvc-repl.man (microsoft-windows-security-ngc-credprov-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_POWERS000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-powershellwebaccess-commands-powershell-migration-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-powershell-ws08-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_POWERS001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-powershell-ws08-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-powershell-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_IE_INT000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-ie-internetexplorer-repl.man (microsoft-windows-ie-internetexplorer-repl-2.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_CREDEN000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-windows-credentialmanagementrole-tools-replacement.man (microsoft-windows-credentialmanagementrole-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_CERTIFICATESER000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-certificateservices-webenrollment-serverupgrade-replacement.man (microsoft-certificateservices-policy-serverupgrade-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_CERTIFICATESER001.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-certificateservices-policy-serverupgrade-replacement.man (microsoft-certificateservices-ocsp-serverupgrade-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_CERTIFICATESER002.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-certificateservices-ocsp-serverupgrade-replacement.man (microsoft-certificateservices-mscep-serverupgrade-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_CERTIFICATESER003.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/microsoft-certificateservices-mscep-serverupgrade-replacement.man (microsoft-certificateservices-ca-serverupgrade-replacement.man)
Using DIRECTORYSERVICES_DOMAIN000.MAN;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/replacementmanifests/directoryservices-domaincontroller-tools-replacement.man (directoryservices-domaincontroller-servercoreupg-replacement.man)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_NETFX3000.CAB;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/sxs/microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab (Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~.cab)
Using MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_INTERN000.CAB;1 for  C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216\Installer\W10-LTSB/W10-LTSB/sources/sxs/microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab (Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~.cab)
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 07:12:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 15:09:33 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 14:54:11 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 14:39:46 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 14:26:09 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 14:13:25 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 14:01:24 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:50:04 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:39:16 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:29:06 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:19:27 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:10:18 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 13:01:32 2020
  0.00% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:53:14 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:45:19 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:37:46 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:30:32 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:23:37 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:17:00 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:10:37 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 12:04:34 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:58:43 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:53:05 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:47:41 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:42:30 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:37:31 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:32:41 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:28:02 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:23:32 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:19:14 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:15:03 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:10:59 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:07:04 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 11:03:18 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 10:59:38 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 10:56:04 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 10:52:38 2020
  0.01% done, estimate finish Mon Jun 08 10:49:18 2020
Total translation table size: 0
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 113516
Total directory bytes: 317932
Path table size(bytes): 2484
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinCDEmu\mkisofs.exe: Implementation botch: FS should end at 4294961215 but ends at 331559.
```

Comment: Why not try NTLite instead (https://www.ntlite.com/download/)? It was designed for that purpose.

Comment: @Didier, thank you, will look into it.

Comment: @Didier, downloaded, how does this help?  The application is not very intuitive and I just don't see what I'm supposed to do with it.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials available on how to use NTLite, but here's one that's fairly didactic: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-create-a-windows-custom-iso-with-updates-using-ntlite . NTLite isn't easy to use, I'll grant you that, but it's the best tool around for you are trying to do.

Comment: Windows natively supports this via [**`oscdimg`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options), which is contained within the [Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) (select Deployment Tools only)

Comment: @JW0914, the issue is that I need to mount an existing ISO so bits of it can be extracted.

Comment: @SPlatten That's not what your question is asking... _"I've unpacked the ISO to a folder and added an AutoUnttend.xml file to the root folder; Now I want to rebuild the ISO."_ The correct tool for the job of rebuilding a WinPE ISO, which is what a Windows install ISO is, is `oscdimg`. It's likely other 3rd party programs work, but when it comes to the Windows install media and process, I've found it's best to rely on the tools created by Microsoft for that job. Just an FYI: you cannot simply re-ISO a Windows install ISO, as it won't boot, which is why `oscdimg` exists.

Comment: @SPlatten _Cont'd..._ It'll likely you take a few times of trial and error to get `oscdimg` to correctly create the ISO and you're going to want to have the Microsoft Docs man page _(linked to previously)_ open to reference while you're creating the command. Start with the basic man page command of `Oscdimg -bC:\winpe_amd64\Efisys.bin -pEF -u1 -udfver102 C:\winpe_amd64\media C:\winpe_amd64\winpeamd64.iso` and customize accordingly, as you may also want to use `-d`, `-n`, `-h`, `-m`, and `-a`; also take a look at the Messaging Options on the man page.

Answer (score -1):

i was restricted on what i could use due to work PC.
i use mkisofs with a batch script as follows.
i pulled most of the mkisofs options from https://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/05/how-to-create-an-iso-image-from-a-folder-linux/

@echo off

REM 1) Download mkisofs-md5-2.01-Binary.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/mkisofs-md5/mkisofs-md5-2.01-Binary.zip

REM 2) Unzip Download mkisofs-md5-2.01-Binary.zip

REM 3) Place Download mkisofs-md5-2.01-Binary in C:\Program Files\

REM 4) Place this script in the parent folder of the folder that the ISO will be created
from

REM 5) The ISO will be created in the Downloads folder

REM NOTE: This will delete the existing output.iso in Downloads!

del /Q %USERPROFILE%"\Downloads\output.iso"

dir

echo --------------------------------------------------------------

set /p Input=Enter the folder name (spaces are OK; enter "." to include all files and folders in the current directory):

"C:\Program Files\mkisofs-md5-2.01-Binary\Binary\MinGW\Gcc-4.4.5\mkisofs.exe" -J -l -R -iso-level 4 -o %USERPROFILE%"\Downloads\output.iso" ".%Input%"

echo --------------------------------------------------------------

echo Done.  Exiting in 5 seconds!

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul